# How can we fix "gem rake-hooks (1) has an invalid gemspec"?

Tags: rubygems

This question comes from a concerned user.  We are trying to use the rake-hooks gem, but `bundle install` gives us an error:

```
Unfortunately, the gem rake-hooks (1) has an invalid gemspec. As a result, Bundler cannot install this Gemfile. Please ask the gem author to yank the bad version to fix this issue. For more information, see http://bit.ly/syck-defaultkey.
```

I assumed it would be a simple thing for the gem owner, so I let them know about the issue (https://github.com/guillermo/rake-hooks/issues/10).  Time passed.  I forgot about it.

Then, the need arose again.  This time I forked the project and tried many things to fix it, including creating a fresh gemspec via `bundle gem rake-hooks`.  I still receive the same error.

What gives?  How could a newly minted gemspec be invalid?
You can find both gemspecs at: https://gist.github.com/2954475

I would really appreciate it if someone could review the gemspec at https://github.com/guillermo/rake-hooks.

Thanks, matt

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2965755

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bundler 1.1.x this could be the problem

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1715

And this the solution:

```
bundle install --full-index
```

It seems to be a problem between bundler 1.1.x and Rubygems indexes.

Comment: As stated above, I get this same error when trying to install it from a local gem package, with a newly generated gemspec.  Are local packages affected by Rubygems indexes?


    gem 'rake-hooks', '1.2.4',
    :require => false,
    :path => '~/develop/gems/rake-hooks'

Comment: Also, thanks for the `--full-index` option.  Unfortunately, my Travis CI build is still failing.

Answer (score 0):

My investigation indicates that version 1 of rake-hooks is causing the issue. I didn't realize, until I was debugging, that the "1" in the error message "rake-hooks (1)" was a version number. The lack of a ".0", as in "1.0", threw me off.

It does seem kind of strange that version "1" is affecting us even if we are specifying version 1.2.3 OR installing a local package, but... the Rubygems guys are recommending we yank the offending version for rubygems.

I have asked the gem owner to yank the offending version.